# SharePoint 2013 blog

Tags: 2013, web-part, blog

I've built a SharePoint 2013 blog.  It is a sub-site of the overall team site.

I was hoping that I could provide a summarized view of the Blog via a web part...similar to how one could create an Announcements list and then provide a summarized view of that Announcements list via a web part on the site's home page.  However, I am not finding any such method to do that.  Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Blog posts are stored in a list, like other SharePoint content. So just add a [content search](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-a-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a) web part to the home page, and point it to the blog posts list from the blog site.